# Modification to JFileChooser to just display folder content

Tags: java, swing, directory, jfilechooser

i m trying to develop an gui application which display tree of filesystem on left side and on right side it display selected tree nodes (folder)'s content .
can any body tell me to do modification in jfilechooser to just to display folder content 
thank you in advance

Comment: Cross-posted in other forums.

Answer (score 1):

The [`JFileChooser#accept`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#accept%28java.io.File%29) allows you to filter which files are displayed. A similar method is the [`JFileChooser#setFileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileFilter%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter%29) method

Comment: i think i was confusing in asking question i just want to display folder content and not want to select any file or folder just want to show folder content which is currently selected in jtree which at left of the jpanel , so i ask any modification can be dont so that only content displaing area of jfilechooser can be displayed and not all buttons like save open and shortcuts at right i hope i m clear thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

See: [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TheJFileChoosersupportsthreeselectionmodesfilesonlydirectoriesonlyandfilesanddirectories.htm)

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Comment: i think i was confusing in asking question i just want to display folder content and not want to select any file or folder just want to show folder content which is currently selected in jtree which at left of the jpanel , so i ask any modification can be dont so that only content displaing area of jfilechooser can be displayed and not all buttons like save open and shortcuts at right i hope i m clear thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you expected:-

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

try {
   // Create a File object containing the canonical path of the desired directory
   File f = new File(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());

   // Set the current directory
   chooser.setCurrentDirectory(f);
} catch (IOException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
}

// Show the dialog; wait until dialog is closed
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    textField.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());

    File[] contents = f.listFiles();
    for(int file=0;file<contents.length;file++)
    {
        System.out.println(contents[file].getName()); //here you get the contents of the selected directory
    }
}
```